# Reorder dataset following Multiple qualitative criteria (Alphabetic Order)

Tags: r

I have a dataset in a list that I called `reord` composed of 521 vectors. Each vector has 14 elements. Only four columns (elements of each single vector) are important to sort this dataset.

I want to create a new dataset that follows the *Alphabetic Order* of these columns: `reord[[i]][10]` then `reord[[i]][2]` then `reord[[i]][3]` and then `reord[[i]][6]`.

- in the *10th column* we have 9 levels: *CAD,CHF,...,...SEK,USD*
- in the *2nd column* we have 3 levels: *A,D,Q*
- in the *3rd column* we have 6 levels: *A,D,I,R,S,T*
- in the *6th column* we have 5 levels: *A,B,C,K,U*

Each of these column will set a group. The *10th column is the more important* (Sets the main order), the *2nd column* follows the 10th (Sets the second order), the *3rd column* follows the 2nd (Sets the third order) and the *6th column* follows the *3rd* (Sets the fourth order).

An Example of the output index (for reorder the original dataset) I'm looking for:

- CAD A A A
- CAD A A B
- CAD A A C
- CAD A A K
- ...
- CAD A D A
- CAD A D B
- CAD A D C
- CAD A D K
- ...
- ...
- CAD Q T U
- CHF A A A
- CHF A A B
- ...
- ...
- ...
- USD Q T U

This is the dataset:

```
reord = list(c("H", "A", "A", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "USD", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", "R", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "I", "B", "5J", 
"A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", 
"R", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", "I", "B", "5J", "U", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "D", "B", "5J", 
"C", "5J", "A", "TO1", "EUR", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"R", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "SEK", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "Q", "C", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "USD", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "U", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "A", "R", "B", "5J", 
"U", "5J", "A", "TO1", "SEK", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", 
"R", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "S", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "D", "B", "5J", 
"U", "5J", "A", "TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"S", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "GBP", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "I", "B", "5J", 
"K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"R", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "CHF", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "A", "T", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "JPY", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "T", "B", "5J", "U", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "Q", "C", "B", "5J", 
"A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "USD", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "A", 
"D", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "EUR", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "A", "S", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", "TO1", "EUR", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "D", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", "R", "B", "5J", 
"B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "SEK", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"R", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "TO1", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", "A", "A", "3", 
"A"), c("H", "D", "I", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "GBP", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "D", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "D", "B", "5J", 
"K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"))
```

This are the grouped elements of each columns

```
##tenth column
tenth = sapply(reord, `[`, 10)
idx10 = split(seq_along(tenth), tenth)

##second column
second = sapply(reord, `[`, 2)              
idx2 = split(seq_along(second), second)

##third column
third = sapply(reord, '[', 3)
idx3 = split(seq_along(third), third)

##sixth column
sixth = sapply(reord, '[', 6)
idx6 = split(seq_along(sixth), sixth)
```

How can I obtain this type of index for reorder the dataset? Thank You

Comment: You say you have a list of *data.frames*. The list you have posted is a list of *vectors*, not data.frames.

Comment: correct, I'm changin it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function corresponds to the problem description.
If the columns to be ordered are not columns 10, 2, 3, 6 like in the question, override the default `cols` argument.

```
fun_order <- function(X, cols = c(10, 2, 3, 6)){
  X <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, X)
  X[] <- lapply(X, as.character)
  names(X) <- seq_along(X)
  i <- do.call(order, X[cols])
  outcols <- c(cols, seq_len(ncol(X))[-cols])
  Y <- X[i, outcols]
  row.names(Y) <- NULL
  list(index = i, cols = cols, data = Y)
}

fun_order(reord)
```

Comment: This is giving me back: "Error in X[,10] : incorrect number of dimensions" in the fun_order function. While in the fun_order2 it gives me back: "Error in do.call(oreder, X[cols]) : the second argument must be a list. So it's not working.

Comment: I think this could work for a dataframe, but the indexing of the lists are different

Comment: this is working great, but the most important thing I need the indices of the row, to order the dataset. Can you add an index to it? thanks

Comment: @Carlo Now the output is a named list with members `index`, `cols` and `data`, the reordered data set. If you only need the index, just comment out the last line and return `i` instead.

Comment: Thank You so much!